# bundle install エラーが表示されインストールできません

Tags: ruby, docker

**実行環境:**
Winodows 1p Pro (64bit)
Vagrant 2.2.14
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Docker 18.09.7
ruby:ruby 2.7.2p137

Docker のコンテ内でRubyのsinatraライブラリをインストールするために
`bundle install` を実行したところ、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.rog/

Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.rog/

Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.rog/

Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.rog/

Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.rog/
```

コンテナを立ち上げた時のコマンドは以下を実行しました。

```
sudo docker container run -it -p 4567:4567 --name sinatra -v ${PWD}/src:/var/www sample/sinatra:latest
```

調べたら、コマンドを実行したら解決したという情報を入手したので

```
 gem update --system
```

を実行して、再度インストールを実行。変化がありません。

`wget https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz` を実行してダウンロードできるか試しましたが、これは成功しました。

ドメインの IP アドレスを調べました。

```
root@dfed40fdb477:/var/www# host api.rubygems.org
api.rubygems.org is an alias for rubygems.org.
rubygems.org has address 151.101.2.132
rubygems.org has address 151.101.130.132
rubygems.org has address 151.101.194.132
rubygems.org has address 151.101.66.132
rubygems.org has IPv6 address 2a04:4e42::644
rubygems.org has IPv6 address 2a04:4e42:200::644
rubygems.org has IPv6 address 2a04:4e42:600::644
rubygems.org has IPv6 address 2a04:4e42:400::644
rubygems.org mail is handled by 10 mxb.mailgun.org.
rubygems.org mail is handled by 10 mxa.mailgun.org.
```

hostファイルに記述しました。

```
151.101.2.132      api.rubygems.org
151.101.130.132    api.rubygems.org
151.101.194.132    api.rubygems.org
151.101.66.132     api.rubygems.org

2a04:4e42::644     api.rubygems.org
2a04:4e42:200::644 api.rubygems.org
2a04:4e42:600::644 api.rubygems.org
2a04:4e42:400::644 api.rubygems.org
```

再度インストールを実行しましたが、変化がありません。

Answer (score 3):

`bundle install` 実行時のエラーメッセージに表示されているドメイン名が `.rog` となっていますが、正しくは `.org`のはずです。
おそらく `Gemfile` の中にタイポがあるのでしょう。

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.rog/
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。タイプミスです。私はどこに目を付けているのだろう。

Comment: Gemfile を作るときは `bundle init` を使うと確実です